# Duplicating a project

Tags: c#, project

I have a project, lots of files, lots of work, etc.

It turns out that I can do a few hours of work, and change it into something totally different; but useful for a debug project elsewhere in the shop.

I want to do that, but create a different app; one which uses the same large amount of existing (tested, and working) code, but just changes some buttons and displays and so on.

What's the best way to do this ? Use the OS to just duplicate the entire file structure ? Then hack the thing ?

Should I start a new project and add the same classes until it's duplicated that way ?

Does C# have some sort of an "import and copy" function ?

Comment: Your "classes" should be in class libraries. Post a picture of what your solution explorer looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What OP and I decided on doing in chat:**

After a long chat discussion this is what OP and I decided on doing for his code:

1. Create a new project (in OP's case WinForms) and solution in visual studio by clicking `File -> New Project`
2. Import the existing code into the new project by right clicking on the new solution and selecting the option `Add -> Existing project` and adding the original project OP needed code from
3. Reference the existing project from the new project by clicking on the `references` part of the new project in the solution explorer and selecting `add reference` and then choosing the project OP wanted to get code from
4. Add `using OLD_PROJECT_NAMESPACE;` to the top of the code in the new project to have access to methods in the old project namespace.

This provides the following benefits:

- Old projects remains unchanged
- New projects shares old project's code like OP asked for

**A more general answer for code sharing scenarios**

You might want to consider making the original program into some sort of more reasonable API. Given that you're using the functionality twice you might do so again. The better thing to do is to extract the classes you'd like to share into a different project and then import it twice, once in the original program and once in the new program.

If you can't do that, here is what I would do:

You're a software shop so I'm assuming you have some form of source control. Most source control programs have some notion of branching your source.

I'd create a new folder, pull the source from the repository and branch it to a different branch.

What you get:

1. You can easily pull bug fixes from the main branch and thus continue to share code between the projects
2. You can easily push bug fixes back to the main branch

Comment: He could also just create a new project and reference existing assemblies, which would be easier.

Comment: @HighCore I agree, I edited my answer to reflect that this is the better option. However OP specifically asked to 'copy' the project.

Comment: Yes, perhaps this is a SVN question, instead of a C# question.  When I tried to checkout a new version, I got the strangest results; recursive into subdirectories I never wanted. I have to wait 20 minutes to ask the question again in that way.

Comment: If you believe that my answer correctly answers your question please accept it. I would still argue against duplicating code (even if it's tracked for you) and for sharing it (through a library project) though

Comment: There's got to be a way where I can just make a dupe of this entire structure, then remove the stuff from form1 and just leave two buttons which will start and stop the debug display. This is horrendously complex. Can't I just copy and open the new one and save it as a new name ?

Comment: You _can_ copy the file structure (copy/paste in the file system) and visual studio will be ok with it, but you _shouldn't_ for the reasons I noted above.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, I was just about to do that. Is there a way I can save the entire project in a different place as a different name ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23738/discussion-between-benjamin-gruenbaum-and-user-1)